# How to deserialize multiple objects from file

Tags: java, deserialization

How do I deserialize multiple objects from a file? Following is code that I have tried which works fine for one object but not for multiple objects.

```
         public List<Show> populateDataFromFile(String fileName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Show s = null;
          //FileInputStream fileIn=null;

          try
          {
              FileInputStream fileIn=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Participant_Workspace\\Q1\\ShowBookingSystem\\ShowDetails.ser");  
                int i=0;  
                while((i=fileIn.read())!=-1){ 
          //   fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Participant_Workspace\\Q1\\ShowBookingSystem\\ShowDetails.ser");
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

             s = (Show) in.readObject();
             in.close();
             fileIn.close();

              System.out.println("Name: " + s.getShowName());
              System.out.println("Show Time: " + s.getShowTime());
              System.out.println("Seats Available: " + s.getSeatsAvailable());
                }
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
             i.printStackTrace();

          }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
          {
             System.out.println("Employee class not found");
             c.printStackTrace();

          }

        return null;
    }
```

I even tried using

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
```

but it did not work. What change do I need to make?

Comment: Why does it seem that this is a exam question and the code you posted is the default body that the question has?

Comment: This is not an exam question. I am applying for job and trying codes so that it can help me for interview.

Comment: You are closing the underlying streams: `in.close(); fileIn.close();`. Try moving those outside the `while` loop and see how it goes.

Comment: @npinti still not working

Comment: When we are using while((i=fin.read())!=-1) , exceptions pops up like java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ED000573
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.util.DataManagerImpl.populateDataFromFile(DataManagerImpl.java:29)
 at com.psl.Client.main(Client.java:12)

Comment: What @npinti asked you to try is keep the original code you posted but move in.close(); fileIn.close(); to outside the while loop

Comment: @Ganesh R. Yes I tried that. After that only exception popped up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
 Show s = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(".....");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    s = (Show) in.readObject();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                   break;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

               System.out.println("Name: " + s.getShowName());
              System.out.println("Show Time: " + s.getShowTime());
              System.out.println("Seats Available: " + s.getSeatsAvailable());
            }

            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
```

Comment: code works well i.e it deserialze the entire file but at the end exception popped up java.io.EOFException at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source) at com.util.DataManagerImpl.populateDataFromFile(DataManagerImpl.java:43) at com.psl.Client.main(Client.java:12)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a short working example. You will need to remove the `ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);` from outside the `while` loop as well.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("...");        
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);    //<- Outside the while loop.
    try            
    {
        while(true)
        {                
            Student std = (Student)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(std.getName());
            System.out.println(std.getAge());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)   
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  //This exception will be thrown if the End Of File (EOF) is reached.
        //
    }
    finally
    {
          fis.close();    //<- Outside the while loop.
          ois.close();    //<- Outside the while loop.
    }
```

Comment: code works well i.e it deserialze the entire file but at the end exception popped up java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at com.util.DataManagerImpl.populateDataFromFile(DataManagerImpl.java:43)
 at com.psl.Client.main(Client.java:12)

Comment: @S1234: That exception is expected, since you are looping indefinitely (`while(true)`). You need this exception to stop the `while` loop from being an infinite loop. In this case it is something you are looking for. Since this is an interview I did not provide an answer to this problem as well.

Comment: can you tell me how to convert data which is String into another format. For example if we have String sn and we want to convert it into Show then how we can do it?

Comment: @S1234: It depends on how you store it. You could write a show object as a comma delimited line in a text file. Then, when reading it back you split the line and initialize the properties accordingly.

Comment: cant we use getShowName

Comment: @npitni something like this try{
                  sn1 =<Show> sn;
              }catch(ClassCastException ex){
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }  where sn holds the values of showname which means sn is of type string and  sn1 is of type show. But it gives error for sn1=<show>sn

Comment: @S1234: I do not think that what you are after can be done in Java. You cannot simply cast a string to an object and expect the JVM to know what to do.

Comment: I have one code for (Iterator<Show> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) { Show a = iter.next(); if(a.getShowName().equals(showname)) { chk=showname; } } if(chk.equals(showname)) { System.out.println("Valid"); } else { System.out.println("Invalid"); } showname is name of show which we are acception from user but whenever we print invalid show name it does not print "Invalid" rather it gives nullpointerexception

Comment: @S1234: You probably need to do something along the lines of `if(iter.hasNext(){Show a = ...}`. Since it might be the case that you are reading beyond the content of the list. Also, please refrain from asking multiple questions in comments. If you have any particular query, please ask a new question and include what have you tried, what are you expecting and what are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution is:

- to put all objects in a list
- serialize the list

This way you **only have one object to de-serialize**: the list. (As a bonus you get your object in a nicely organised (or not!) list).

If you have multiples type of object to serialize, serialize them in a list per class. Each list in a different file.